# Select value from drop down autocomplete

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I use cssselector with Keys class. But the value is not selected

```
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")).sendKeys("Odes", Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER);
```

I want to select the value Odessa from drop down list:

[image]

Comment: Please post a link to the page or at least the relevant HTML.. the HTML of the dropdown especially. You state you want to select Odessa but every value in that dropdown contains Odessa... which Odessa do you want to select? 'Odessa (UKR)' or ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle dropdown value

```
 - dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Text");
 - dropdown.selectByIndex(2); (Index starts with zero always in list)
 - dropdown.selectByValue(“Text”)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
    Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")));

// Select option (Odessa(UKR))
    oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Odessa(UKR)"); // Using sleep command so that changes can be noticed
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // : Select option 'using Index 
    oSelect.selectByIndex(1);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    //  Print all the options for the selected drop down and select one option of your choice
    // Get the size of the Select element
    List<WebElement> oSize = oSelect.getOptions();
    int iListSize = oSize.size();

    // Setting up the loop to print all the options
    for(int i =0; i < iListSize ; i++){
        // Storing the value of the option  
        String sValue = oSelect.getOptions().get(i).getText();
        // Printing the stored value
        System.out.println(sValue);
        // Putting a check on each option that if any of the option is equal to 'Africa" then select it 
        if(sValue.equals("Odessa(UKR)")){
            oSelect.selectByIndex(i);
            break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("XXXXX"))); - is this id of my drop down list?

Comment: Thread.sleep(2000);
            oSelect.selectByIndex(1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Select oSelect = new Select(browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")));

// Select option (Odessa(UKR))
            oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Odessa(UKR)"); // Using sleep command so that changes can be noticed
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // : Select option 'using Index
            oSelect.selectByIndex(1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

Comment: Can you please provide DOM or url  ?

Comment: i cant give you url(((

Comment: Can you please share DOM structure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the website is populating that dropdown, but maybe you could enter your text and then select the first option like this:

```
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")).sendKeys("Odes");

browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")).findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(0).click()
    /** OR */
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']:first-child")).click()
```

Sorry, I'm not familiar with java or cssSelectors... just Selenium. If you can clean up that code, that should work if the website is dynamically adding options to the dom.

One more using xpath:
`browser.findElement(By.xpath("input[@id='loadingPort']/option[1]")).click()`

Comment: browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='loadingPort']")).findElements(By.tagName("option")).get(0).click()    - option - it is a tag of drop down list?

Comment: Yes. Usually, drop downs are a `select` tag with each option being an `option` child tag. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp